# Arduino / Love-O-Meter : wrong temperature read when LEDs are on

Tags: arduino, sensor

I tried the Love-O-Meter example given in the Startup kit of Arduino. The example is available [here](https://create.arduino.cc/projecthub/godboi123/love-o-meter-bda552). The temperature sensor is the TMP36 given with the kit.

If the three LEDs are off (e.g. when writing `LOW` in the code, comment the corresponding lines or unplug them), there is no problem: the real temperature in the room is given and the sensor gives a value around 150.

However, if one or more LEDs are on, then the temperature increases to around 10°C for each LED (the sensor gives 215 when the three LEDS are on).

The conversion from the sensor value to the temperature works well. Also, I measure a correct voltage by using a multimeter.

Any idea?

Answer (score 2):

**Run a separate ground connection for the temperature sensor.**

The way it is shown in the picture of the link, The LEDs are sharing the ground connection, and this is causing a slight ground reference shift (voltage drop), which is causing the output voltage to be shifted with respect to the A2D ground reference.

Comment: Gah, you were 7 seconds faster. :D